# Detect resumable download capacity

Tags: iphone, ios, download, resume

I wrote an iphone application used for download file from internet with resume download functionality.

I use below method for resume download functionality.:

```
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bytes=%lld-",value] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Range"];
```

In normal case, the application works well. When file from internet don't support resume download capacity, the resume functionality don't start at specified position but start at begin position.

How we can detect resumable download capacity of file from internet?

Comment: http://nachbaur.com/blog/resuming-large-downloads-with-nsurlconnection